# C# bruteforce application doesn't print anything when debugging and terminates when password is more than 1 letters long

Tags: c#, .net-core, stack-overflow, brute-force

I have made this "bruteforce" program, but when I run it using algorithm 2 and the password is more than 1 letter, it stops and says: `Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.`
Also, when I try to debug this, it does not start and ask for the algorithm number. What do I do wrong? (I know the code is bad but you can still give me feedback and improvement ideas.)

Using .NET Core on Linux and VSCode.

```
class Program
{
    static string chars = "- -a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l-m-n-o-p-q-r-s-t-u-v-w-x-y-z-A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9";
    static string[] c = chars.Split("-");
    static string password = "";
    static string attempt = "";
    static Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    static int i_max_length = 1;

    static char first = Char.Parse(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(32));
    static char last = Char.Parse(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(126));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        Console.Write("Algorithm: (1/2) ");
        string algorithm = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.Write("Enter password: ");
        password = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        Program.sw.Start();

        if (algorithm == "1")
        {
            Start("");
        }
        else if (algorithm == "2")
        {
            CharForce("");
        }
    }
    static void Start(string previous)
    {
        if (previous.Length >= i_max_length)
            return;

        foreach (string ch in Program.c)
        {
            attempt = previous + ch;
            //Console.WriteLine("{0}", attempt);
            if (attempt == password)
            {
                Program.sw.Stop();
                TimeSpan time = sw.Elapsed;
                Console.WriteLine("Password: {0}", attempt);
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.ToString());
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        foreach (string ch in Program.c)
        {
            Start(previous + ch);
        }
    }
    static void CharForce(string p)
    {
        if (attempt != password)
        {
            if (p.Length >= i_max_length)
                return;

            for (char f = first; f <= last; f++)
            {
                attempt = p + f;
                CharForce(p + f);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Program.sw.Stop();
            TimeSpan time = sw.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine("Password: {0}", attempt);
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.ToString());
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using recursion is dangerous when you don't have strong prediction that the recursion depth wouldn't exceed the stack size and should be avoided, otherwise the moment when you get a `StackOverflowException` is only a matter of time. I'd suggest to use loops or trampolining as a safe alternative of recursion.

Comment: The best way you can improve is by [learning how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). This is a critical skill for programmers and if yours “does not start” you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You get the `StackOverflowException` if you either got a Infinite Recursion, or at least something so big that Windows decides "propably Infinite" - and kills that line.

You did not specify wich line the Exception is from, but recursions is in these two parts:

```
    foreach (string ch in Program.c)
    {
        Start(previous + ch);
    }



    for (char f = first; f <= last; f++)
    {
        attempt = p + f;
        CharForce(p + f);
    }
```

Additionally your programm flow is utterly broken. You have several manual `Environment.Exit(0);`?

If this is supposed to be Multitasking (wich it really should be), you propably should not be doing it in Console. For Learning Multitasking and in Particular Multithreading (for this one it might work), I usually advise for the BackgroundWorker in a WindowsForms application.

Comment: To get `StackOverflowException` you not necessarily need an infinite recursion - a simple recursion with depth which exceeds the stack size is enough to get this exception. And btw, Windows doesn't **decide** anything on that - the exception is thrown by SEH and then by .NET runtime when stack boundaries are violated.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov I am confused. I said the exact same thing: "or at least something so big that Windows decides "propably Infinite"" | Also the SEH *is* Windows: "Microsoft Structured Exception Handling is the native exception handling mechanism for Windows and a forerunner technology to Vectored Exception Handling (VEH).[1] It features the finally mechanism not present in standard C++ exceptions (but present in most imperative languages introduced later). SEH is set up and handled separately for each thread of execution. "

Comment: That's not the same: `Windows decides "propably Infinite"` has nothing to do with exceeded stack boundaries. This statement at least misleading as there is neither conception nor definition of **probably infinite** inside infrastructure which throws this exception.

Comment: As for the `SEH is Windows` it's like to say that a wheel is a car.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov I am actually saying that Cars have Wheels. Also I think most people get run over by a car, not by a wheel. So the precise part doing stuff on you does not mater that much. | My main point was that it was infinite recursions or at elast something so deep it was asumed to be Infinite recursion.

Comment: Technically there is no notion of infinite recursion and no infrastructure tries to detect, `decide` or `assume` whether a recursion is infinite, probably infinite, semi-infinite or whatever else infinite.

Comment: Thanks. VSCode actually doesn't tell me in which line the StackOverflowException is when I run it using dotnet run because the debugging doesn't work. Also I'm using console because I'm on Linux.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov "Technically there is no notion of infinite recursion and no infrastructure tries to detect, decide or assume whether a recursion is infinite, probably infinite, semi-infinite or whatever else infinite." So the StackOverflowException does not exist or is not thrown? That is a interesting Philosophical point. But not really talking about reality now.

Comment: @xNPx3 The debugger not working is a serious issues for debugging, obviously. But in the end any GUI technology works. The part of having a Event Loop to send callbacks too and keep the application alive really helps with getting going there. And this is a rare case where actually Multithreading might work.

Comment: @Christopher absence of a notion you made up doesn't imply absence of `StackOverfloException` as it's only your personal assumption that there is a relationship between these two. I'm talking about real engineering things - you seem to talk about some ephemeral conceptions and this is really sad as the answer is supposed to be read by future readers and this can simply mislead them.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov You are the one that started this discussion to split hairs. You have gone more and more off the question. There is a protection from Infinite Recrusion. It was triggered. Sometimes that happens in error, but most likely not.

Comment: @Christopher I'm not off the question while your answer contains `or at least something so big that Windows decides "propably Infinite" - and kills that line` statement which has nothing to do with reality. Simple.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov 40 < Infinity. If I use this as limit to the Call Stack, a amount of 40 will trigger it. This can be due to a genuine Infinite recursion. Or just a really big non-infinite one. Nothing else I said.

Comment: @Christopher, you said this only in comment, the answer still contains this absurd about decision on `probably Infinite` and killing the line. Now about infinite recursion - there is always limit in the system and it simply isn't ware of whether your recursion is supposed to never end or just has 41 iterations, so technically it never happens unlike infinite loop  and can be only be algorithmically confirmed but I cannot see an algorithmical analysis in your answer.

Comment: @Christopher,  Fyi, in case you given it may fail on 41, 42, 43 as well as on many other number of iterations which are far from being infinite, so just count how many scenarios it can fail on without being in algorithmical infinite recursive loop which is just speculatively brought to the table.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov  40 < Infinity. If I use this as limit to the Call Stack, a amount of 40 will trigger it. This can be due to a genuine Infinite recursion. Or just a really big non-infinite one. Nothing else I said.

Comment: You don't need to post it twice I've already seen that and explained why your answer is incorrect.